# How do you format code in Sublime Text editor 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How I can format, or beautify php,html,css,javascript code in the Sublime 3 Text editor?

When I go into Edit menu of Sublime 3 there is no option for formatting or beautifying code!

Comment: Select all and then choose Edit -> Indent Document ( Ctrl + Alt + I )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, [install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), the package manager for Sublime Text. Next, you need to install packages that do what you're after: [beautify code](https://packagecontrol.io/search/beautify) or maybe just [indent](https://packagecontrol.io/search/indent) it.

Comment: You can try also https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeFormatter

Comment: FYI, CodeFormatter breaks with PHP7.2